# Earth alternative

Tags: adc, emc, isolation, load-cell, earth

I'm designing an industrial machine which is AC motor derived. There are sensitive analog sensors (e.g. Load cell) in the system and in the user's site, Unfortunately  earth connection is not available and it caused poor EMC performance on analog side of the system. For instance, the metal case of the system has about 80V potential and it is injected to ADC chip by load cell shield. I would like to know, is there any solution to reduce EMI without earth connection?

Any help would be highly appreciated,
William

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the 80 volts on the shield gets into the ADC input. Maybe show a diagram?

Comment: STOP! Do not skimp on earth connections. It's just not worth it!

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what locality you are situated in and so there may be certain regulatory requirements to be met in addition to my recommendation here. But STOP working on equipment (industrial or otherwise) that has exposed metal parts and shields that are not earth connected. If there is no earth connection get one installed ASAP.

Anytime there is mains AC power in use safety needs to be the primary concern even before you try to figure out your circuitry problems. So get the earth connections properly installed and then you can try to figure out your sensor shielding.